# How to remove a place holder in a text file with text from another file when multiple lines are present?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, perl, yaml

I have a file:

```
  - id: 1.4.25.2
    name: 'Configuring a VNC Server'
    permalink: '/rhcsa/managing-network-services/configuring-vnc-access/configuring-a-vnc-server'
    description: '<*description>'
    content: []
  - id: 1.4.25.3
    name: 'Connecting to a VNC Server'
    permalink: '/rhcsa/managing-network-services/configuring-vnc-access/connecting-to-a-vnc-server'
    description: '<*description>'
    content: []
```

I have to replace each `<*description>` with some text. Obviously, I thought of using regex. Apparently (according to certain answers on this site), `sed` doesn't have a non-greedy modifier for substitutions. Thus, I tried using perl:

```
(.*id: 1\.4\.25\.2(?:\n|.)*)\'(\<\*description\>)\'
```

doesn't select the required part, which would be from `- id: 1.4.25.2` till `description: '<*description>'\ncontent: []`, right before the next element in the yaml array, i.e., before the line `- id: 1.4.25.3`. I can't figure out a way to do this, and how I could change the description of each entry in the file with a custom text lifted from some place else!

Comment: It's unclear what should replace the placeholder. BTW, Perl has YAML libraries.

Comment: just a few questions: you're looking to replace all the descriptions, not just one? where and how are the descriptions held? are they just in another file?

Comment: post your so-called *another file* content and the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a YAML module; recurse through the data structure and replace any matching elements here with lines read in on standard input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use YAML::Tiny;

my $yaml =
  YAML::Tiny->read( $ARGV[0] // die "Usage: $0 yaml-file [out-file]\n" );

mangle_description( $yaml->[0] );

$yaml->write( $ARGV[1] // "$ARGV[0].out" );

sub mangle_description {
    my $what = shift;
    my $type = ref $what;
    if ( $type eq 'HASH' ) {
        for my $key ( keys %$what ) {
            if ( $key eq 'description'
             and $what->{$key} eq '<*description>' ) {
                $what->{$key} = set_description();
            }
            mangle_description( $what->{$key} ) if ref $what->{$key};
        }
    } elsif ( $type eq 'ARRAY' ) {
        for my $entry (@$what) {
            mangle_description($entry);
        }
    } else {
        warn Dumper $what;
        die "unknown type in YAML ??\n";
    }
}

sub set_description {
    my $next = readline *STDIN;
    chomp $next;
    return $next;
}
```

the above saved as `parser` and with valid YAML in `input`:

```
$ yes | perl parser input
$ grep description input.out
    description: y
    description: y
$
```

Comment: This is great! Qould u say there would be performance issues if i use Python instead of Perl? Im more familiar with it..

Comment: I couldn't say; I avoid using python for various reasons